# Dynamically Store a String in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to obtain and transfer information from a HTML web form (through input text field), then store that info into another file within a PHP variable.  As you can see below, I have created a string to search ($str_to_find) and manually used 'script' for the string, but what I want to do is fill this area dynamically with information from a web form in another file.

I know this may be a general question, but I have not clue where to start.

```
function check_files($this_file) {
$str_to_find='script'; // the string(code/text) to search for
//I want to fill the 'string' above with info from another file's web form, if possible.
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use something like `file_get_contents()` (here is the documentation page for that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)  There are some examples near the middle of that page that should help you get started... at least as far as the file part goes!

Comment: Ok....that makes sense.  I guess my question is how what code would I use to accomplish that if coming from a text field inside of a web form?  I think I'm confused as to putting that into program language

Comment: It's debatable whether or not your method, or using a database is more complicated, but maybe this could be done using a simple [SQLite Database](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlite.php)?  If you have PHP 5 or greater, SQLite is enabled by default and you could read and write values from a sqlite database which is stored in a single file on disk.  *Perhaps you could clarify on your ultimate goal for the form and the data being stored/retrieved?*

Comment: It sounds like you've taken an unusual and haphazard approach to something relatively simple. If you can explain your end goal more clearly, we can help get you on the right path.

Comment: I'm actually pulling input from a user in the Wordpress admin. It's plugin, actually.  I just need to store user input that will be given through the admin, then I want to process that input in another php file. The output will be shown directly under the field where the user enters this information.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about what you're trying to achieve? If you just want to access the information the user posted, then the $_GET or $_POST variable may be what you're after. Once you have that, then as @summea suggested, you can use `file_get_contents()` to do your search... but I could also be completely misunderstanding your question. So, more info please?

Comment: @RobMyrick Once a form is `POST`ed (in PHP,) you can access that submitted form information with the $_POST array variable!  Then, all you would have to do is use `file_get_contents()` to save that $_POST variable to a file.  ($_POST documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) Any general idea of what type of WordPress plugin you are making?

Comment: Okay.....I'm simply just showing results of a search that will be provided by the user through a web form.  The user will enter this info through a Plugin settings panel in the Worpdress admin.  Kind of like Google....I will be taking a string from user input in one file, then processing that search string through another file and displaying the results on that same page.

Comment: @RobMyrick based on your comments, it seems like you may actually be after an AJAX-type solution. Is that right? If so, then $_GET or $_POST may be what you're after, and then a bit of JavaScript to handle the display the information passed back.

Comment: summea could I chat with you quickly or email you regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use GET or POST data. Here is basic sample. A person will fill in the form on form.html and click submit. You will then collect the POST data from this form by the attribute names. In this case the process.php script just prints out "`Hello <firstname> <lastname>`" but alternatively you can display it as you wish.

*form.html*

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
  <input name="fname" type="text" />
  <input name="lname" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

*process.php*

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
echo "Hello $fname $lname"
...
```

If you want this to display information on the same page, you can use AJAX. Refer to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for examples. I have included one below:

*form.html*

```
...
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // when document is ready do this
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // listen to when users click on the send button
        $('#send-ajax').click(function() {

            // get input data
            $fname = $('#fname').val();
            $lname = $('#lname').val();

            // result container
            $result = $('#result-ajax');

            // create ajax request to process and store
            // result in the div container above the form
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'HTML',
                data: {
                    fname: $fname,
                    lname: $lname
                },
                success: function($html) {
                    $result.html($html);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $result.html('<b>Request Failed</b>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result-ajax"></div>
    <input id="fname"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ />
    <input id="lname" />
    <button id="send-ajax" value="send">Send</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</body>
...
```

*process.php*

**Same as above**

Comment: Thanks Prowla, your answer did the trick. Very practical thank you.  If you're still around in the forum, do you know how I could post the data in the process.php inside of an iframe?  I run the script and it opens up process.php inside of a new browser window. I just want the results to be shown inside of an iframe on the same page.  Is that where I need to use AJAX instead?

Comment: I won't go into reasons why but don't use iframes. I will update my answer to include an AJAX request